# clang tautological-constant-out-of-range-compare warning

Tags: c, clang, compiler-warnings

If I compile the following simple program (test.c) using clang

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    a,
    b
} sample_enum_t;


int main() {
    sample_enum_t sample_enum = -1;
    if (sample_enum == -1) {
        printf("Equals\n");
    }
}
```

The compiles gives me a warning:

```
$ clang -o test test.c
test.c:11:21: warning: comparison of constant -1 with expression of type 'sample_enum_t' is always false [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
    if (sample_enum == -1) {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
1 warning generated.
```

It is clearly not true that the comparison is always false, if I execute the program it prints at "Equals":

```
$ ./test 
Equals
```

Is it a clang bug or I'm missing something? I do understand that assigning -1 to the sample_enum variable is not a very good idea, but it's a valid line and clang does not give me a warning because of that line.

*I'm using clang 3.5.2*

Comment: [This Clang issue seems relevant](https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=16154). It's not closed, so I'm not sure if it has been addressed. My understanding is that they think it's a useful warning, but it should be re-formulated to prevent people from removing code based on the warning.

Comment: Ouch, that bugreport is 3.5 years old.

Comment: Going to share a real world example that elicits this clang warning: https://github.com/golems/ach/blob/4766faa88fc24331d78005df9d218710250efab8/src/libach.c#L91-L95

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring whether Clang is right or wrong for the moment, let's look at what the standard says.

[6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p4):

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,128) but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration. The enumerated type is incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates the list of enumerator declarations, and complete thereafter.
>
> 128) An implementation may delay the choice of which integer type until all enumeration constants have been seen.

You are relying on *implementation-defined* behaviour; whether the type your implementation chooses can represent `-1` isn't defined by the standard.
Both Clang and GCC use `unsigned int` (in my testing for your code using gcc 7.0.1 and clang 3.8.0). So, your code is valid as there's no issue representing -1.

So, this is not a real issue and Clang's diagnostic is somewhat useful, in that if you have unintentionally used some value outside the range of enum constants you have defined.

Comment: "Both Clang and GCC use unsigned int" Isn't that an issue for `-1`?

Comment: @rootkea Assigning -1 to `unsigned int` has well-defined semantics: it'll be converted into value representable in `unsigned int` using reduction modulo; it's equivalent to
assigning `UINT_MAX`. While comparing -1 with `unsigned int` type, -1 will be converted in the same way e.g., `-1 == UINT_MAX` will always be true. So, there's no issue assigning -1 to any unsigned type (except there's not much practical reason/use to do so).